# inefficient Linq statement

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have the following code to extract customer address as Latitude/Longitude points from an sql database and display points on a winforms Map.  However, the database is quite large and this takes a very long time to simply complete the foreach.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
public static List<MyAppMaps.MapPoints> GetAddresses()
{
    List<MyAppMaps.MapPoints> addresses = new List<MyAppMaps.MapPoints>();

    try
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext dataClassesDataContext = new DataClassesDataContext(cDbConnection.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            var query = (from customer in dataClassesDataContext.Customers
                where (customer.Address.Latitude != ""
                       || customer.Address.Longitude != "")
                select customer);

            if (query.ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Customer item in query)
                {
                    MyAppMaps.MapPoints address = new MyAppMaps.MapPoints();

                    address.Lat = item.Address.Latitude;
                    address.Long = item.Address.Longitude;
                    addresses.Add(address);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    return addresses;
}
```

Comment: how many results are you getting?

Comment: You can start with removing useless `if (query.ToList().Count > 0)` check, which makes your query execute 2 times instead of 1. No need to use `Any` - just remove it completely.

Comment: First of all replace `.ToList().Count` to `.Any()`...

Comment: there are around 15,000 results

Comment: Why is `||` used rather than `&&`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you access `Address` property, which probably points to a different table, which is then lazily loaded during the `foreach` (meaning each iteration causes another query).

That is something you need to make sure to avoid when working with Entity Framework. If you directly want to include something in the response, use `Include` method to avoid additional queries under-the-hood. However, usually it is best to use `Select` projection to return really what you actually need, which will keep the data transfer at the lowest possible rate.

You should use `Select` to return just the address you need:

```
var query = (from customer in dataClassesDataContext.Customers
                where (customer.Address.Latitude != ""
                       || customer.Address.Longitude != "")
                select customer.Address);
```

You also call `ToList()` to check if there are any items. That executes the query unnecessarily. You can either call `ToList()` right away and then use the created list, or just use `Any` to check if there are actually any items with a light-weight query.

Overall you could improve the code like follows:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext dataClassesDataContext = new DataClassesDataContext(cDbConnection.GetConnectionString()))
{
    var query = from customer in dataClassesDataContext.Customers
        where (customer.Address.Latitude != ""
               || customer.Address.Longitude != "")
        select new MyAppMaps.MapPoints() { Longitude = customer.Address.Longitude, Latitude = customer.Address.Latitude };
    addresses.AddRange( query );
}
```

### Update

As suggested by @Evk, you can improve even further by just returning the two required fields instead of the whole `Address` instance. I have updated the code to reflect this.

### Update 2

Simplified even more based on @Sivaprasath's suggestion - adding the results to the address list via a LINQ query instead.

Comment: It worth selecting just `Latitude` and `Longitude` fields, who knows how many useless (for this task) fields address table contains...

Comment: Great idea, I have updated my answer with this improvement

Comment: And i guess we don't need to loop it again to create a MapPoints objects instead we can use in the statement itself as below, select new MapPoints(){ Long = customer.Address.Longitude, Lat = customer.Address.Latitude } and when we do items.ToList() itself we will get the list of map points.

Comment: this is excellent, thank you.  I have identified a lot of inefficient code just like this in the app and will start optimising based on yours and everyone's suggestions.  Much appreciated

Comment: instant conversion (was > 5 mins to do just this).  Although it was a one-off task, I have identified code similar to this through the software!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a projection right in the LINQ to avoid pulling the data that you don't need:

```
var addresses = dataClassesDataContext.Customers.
    .Select(c => c.Address)
    .Where(a => a.Latitude != "" || a.Longitude != "")
    .Select(c => new {
        a.Latitude
    ,   a.Longitude
    }).AsEnumerable() // From this point on LINQ is in memory
    .Select(p => new MyAppMaps.MapPoints {
        Lat = p.Latitude, Long = p.Longitude
    }).ToList();
```

This simplified version should work as well:

```
var addresses = dataClassesDataContext.Customers.
    .Select(c => c.Address)
    .Where(a => a.Latitude != "" || a.Longitude != "")
    .Select(a => new MyAppMaps.MapPoints {
        Lat = a.Latitude, Long = a.Longitude
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why not just project into MyPoints without intermediate anonymous type? Also, one can just start with address (`dataClassesDataContext.Addresses.Where(...)`) instead of going to them though customers.

Comment: @Evk Going through customers ensures that addresses that do not belong to customers (say, vendor addresses and company addresses) and/or "orphaned" addresses are not pulled from the DB. I'll edit to add a simplified version.

Comment: thanks, this is good and based on your and above answers I am in the process of going through my LINQ code and this has identified some very lazy / inefficient coding.  Good work and thank you.